# Populate a CSV column according to the value of another column

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk

In a Bash script, I want to populate one currently empty column (column 5) according to the values of another (column 1).

I think I can use `awk` in order to achieve the desired result, but I'm having problems with the syntax:

```
awk -F, '
$1~/sld_[a-z]{3}[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}_f_[0-9]{3}[a-z]\.tif$/{$5="Text"}
$1~/sld_[a-z]{3}[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}_[a-b]_[0-9]{1,3}[a-z]?\.tif$/{$5="Front matter"}
$1~/sld_[a-z]{3}[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}_y_[0-9]{1,3}[a-z]?\.tif$/{$5="Back matter"}
$1~/sld_[a-z]{3}[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}_z_1[a-z]?\.tif$/{$5="Back matter"}
' file.csv
```

My input looks like this:

```
File Name,Item Sequence,Visibility,Title
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0001_a_1.tif,1,discovery,Front Board Outside
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0002_a_1a.tif,2,discovery,Front Board Outside
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0003_b_000.tif,3,discovery,Front Board Inside
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0009_b_003v.tif,9,discovery,Flyleaf 003v
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0010_f_001r.tif,10,discovery,f. 001r
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0060_y_001r.tif,60,discovery,Flyleaf 001r
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0070_y_999.tif,70,discovery,Back Board Inside
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0071_z_1.tif,71,discovery,Back Board Outside
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0072_z_1a.tif,72,discovery,Back Board Outside
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0073_z_2.tif,73,discovery,Spine
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0074_z_3.tif,74,discovery,Fore edge
```

And the desired result should look like what appears below where the fifth column (`IIIF Range`) has been populated by the values I assigned above (`Front matter`, `Text`, `Back matter`, and blank) based on the values of column 1 (`File Name`):

```
File Name,Item Sequence,Visibility,Title,IIIF Range
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0001_a_1.tif,1,discovery,Front Board Outside,Front matter
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0002_a_1a.tif,2,discovery,Front Board Outside,Front matter
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0003_b_000.tif,3,discovery,Front Board Inside,Front matter
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0009_b_003v.tif,9,discovery,Flyleaf 003v,Front matter
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0010_f_001r.tif,10,discovery,f. 001r,Text
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0060_y_001r.tif,60,discovery,Flyleaf 001r,Back matter
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0070_y_999.tif,70,discovery,Back Board Inside,Back matter
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0071_z_1.tif,71,discovery,Back Board Outside,Back matter
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0072_z_1a.tif,72,discovery,Back Board Outside,Back matter
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0073_z_2.tif,73,discovery,Spine,,  
Masters/sinaimasters/ara/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0074_z_3.tif,74,discovery,Fore edge,,
```

Comment: [edit] your question to include **textual** (not an image and not a link) concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. Also include everything required for this question to stand alone, don't include a link to some other question and hope people will go read that trying to piece together what you're currently asking about. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Posting links to samples doesn't really help, I'm not even gonna click them. Please just create a [mcve] and include it in your question

Comment: Is there a version of awk that understands things like `\w` and `\d`?

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for your feedback; please see the edited version of my question.

Comment: Thanks @oguzismail for your feedback; please see the edited version of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `~` operator to match a string against a regex pattern:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}
$1~/sld_[a-z]{3}[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}_f_[0-9]{3}[a-z]\.tif$/{$5="Text"}
$1~/sld_[a-z]{3}[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}_[a-b]_[0-9]{1,3}[a-z]?\.tif$/{$5="Front matter"}
$1~/sld_[a-z]{3}[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}_y_[0-9]{1,3}[a-z]?\.tif$/{$5="Back matter"}
$1~/sld_[a-z]{3}[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}_z_1[a-z]?\.tif$/{$5="Back matter"}
1' file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. The errors I would get went away, but this ```awk``` didn't affect the output and the fifth column is all blank.

Comment: What's the field separator of your CSV? You should specify it with the `-F` option if it isn't spaces.

Comment: It's comma-separated, and I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: In that case you'd need the `-F,` option. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: Still it doesn't affect the results. I don't know what might be causing it.

Comment: Are you sure your input is really comma-separated? From the example you give in your question it looks like your input is really tab-separated. If that's the case, try using the `-F'\t'` option.

Comment: It is comma separated as I've used the comma delimiter elsewhere in the script. Can you try it on your own end as well?

Comment: Can you updated your question with a sample of the exact input you have, so that I can help test? As it is, your sample input in the question are definitely not comma-separated. There isn't even a comma anywhere.

Comment: Just did. Please see above. Thanks!

Comment: Oops I just realized I forgot the `1` in the end to output the buffer, and to set the output field separator `OFS` in the `BEGIN` block. I've tested my updated answer with your updated input and can confirm that it is now working.